# API error (500): Container command not found or does not exist

Tags: kubernetes

kubectl describe pods 
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RaQH.jpg)

pods logs
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsZ1q.jpg)

`command:
        - bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn/production.rb -E production`

The container can't start on k8s  and some errors occured .

But when I exec

`docker run  -d  image [CMD]`

The container works well.

Answer (score 0):

"command" is an array, so each argument has to be a separate element, not all on one line

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this problem:

make sure the gems (including unicorn) are actually installed in the volume used by the container. If not, do a **bundle install**.

Another reason for this kind of error could be that the directory specified under working_dir (in the docker-compose.yml) does not exist (see [Misleading error message "ERROR: Container command not found or does not exist."](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2950)).